# Menu Dropdown (VUEJS/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dropdown, vue.js

Estou tentando fazer um menu dropdown no Vue (não quero usar Bootstrap-vue), então criei um `isActiveDrop` e defini como `true`, e sempre que clico no botao para abrir ele é definido como `false`, assim o menu aparece e some, porem como faria para esse menu sumir ao clicar fora? sem ter que clicar no icone, apenas clicando fora dele?

```
<i class="fa fa-menu" @click="menu"></i>

<ul  :class="{hidden: isActiveDrop}">
  <li>TESTE</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá,

Procurando uma maneira simples de implementar a funcionalidade ***click-outside*** no elemento, encontrei esta [`directive`](https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/Lx49LaL8/). Alias, não achei outra maneira se não por diretivas.

Abaixo está uma adequação da `directive` para `ES5` e mais algumas modificações.

```
Vue.directive('click-out', {
  bind: function(element, binding, node) {
    // verifica se o parametro da diretiva é diferente de um objeto do tipo function.
    if(typeof binding.value !== 'function') {
      var component = node.context.name;
      var text = '[Vue-click-out:] a expressão informada deve ser uma função';
      if(component) {
        text += ' Component: ' + component;
      };
      console.warn(text);
    };
    // cria o evento e atribui ao elemento
    var bubble = binding.modifiers.bubble;
    var handler = function(evt) {
      if(bubble || (!element.contains(evt.target) && element !== evt.target)) {
        binding.value(evt);
      };
    };
    element.__vueClickOutside__ = handler;
    // adiciona o evento que trata os cliques fora do component
    document.addEventListener('click', handler);
  },

  unbind: function(element) {
    // remove o evento que trata cliques fora do componente
    document.removeEventListener('click', element.__vueClickOutside__);
    element.__vueClickOutside__ = null;
  }
});
```

#Implementação

Registrando a diretiva acima em seu código, um exemplo de utilização ficará assim:

```js
Vue.directive('click-out', {
  bind: function(element, binding, node) {
    // verifica se o parametro da diretiva é diferente de um objeto do tipo function.
    if (typeof binding.value !== 'function') {
      var component = node.context.name;
      var text = '[Vue-click-out:] a expressão informada deve ser uma função';
      if (component) {
        text += ' Component: ' + component;
      };
      console.warn(text);
    };
    // cria o evento e atribui ao elemento
    var bubble = binding.modifiers.bubble;
    var handler = function(evt) {
      if (bubble || (!element.contains(evt.target) && element !== evt.target)) {
        binding.value(evt);
      };
    };
    element.__vueClickOutside__ = handler;
    // adiciona o evento que trata os cliques fora do component
    document.addEventListener('click', handler);
  },

  unbind: function(element) {
    // remove o evento que trata cliques fora do componente
    document.removeEventListener('click', element.__vueClickOutside__);
    element.__vueClickOutside__ = null;
  }
});

var navList = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      visible: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    show: function() {
      this.visible = !this.visible;
    },
    hide: function() {
      this.visible = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.3.4/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li @click="show" v-click-out="hide">
      Products
      <ul class="dropdown" :class="{active: visible}">
        <li>Product 1</li>
        <li>Product 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>About us</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Basicamente você tem o `v-bind` ou `:` para `class` verificando se `visible` é verdadeiro (`true`) e atribuindo a class `.active` se for o caso. Também o `v-on` ou `@` para o evento `click`, atribuindo pelo método `show`, `true` ou `false` (o contrário do valor atual na propriedade) a `visible` e a `directive` `v-click-out`, atribuindo pelo método `hide`,  `false` a `visible`.

#Teste

```
...<li @click="show" v-click-out="visible = true">...
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso desta diretiva é possível somente informar um método para execução, porém você pode adequá-la para receber uma expressão do [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/).

#Informações

Mais sobre `custom directives` (diretivas) no VueJS 2.x [aqui](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html).